# Prove a trigonometric identity for $\tan\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Needs to be proved:

$$\frac{\sin(\theta) - 2\sin^3(\theta)}{ 2\cos^3(\theta) - \cos(\theta)} = \tan(\theta)$$

Homework for my sister. She has already tried solving but not getting it. 
I am clueless anyone can help with steps, much appreciated?

Comment: So what do I have to do? Solve it? Prove it? What?????

Comment: Needs to be proved LHS = RHS

Comment: Is LHS really equal to RHS?

Comment: Please check that the identity is stated correctly, not just "somewhat like that".

Comment: Yes, the identity is not correct... maybe it should be $2\sin^3$ not $2 \sin^2$.

Comment: The identity fails under $\theta = 45^\circ$.

Comment: Clearly incorrect, put $\theta = \pi/4$ and it's not true

Comment: Thanks Norman, the identity is correct

Comment: Put $$\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$$ and you get $L.H.S. \not = R.H.S.$

Comment: @Gregory, that should be it, but even in that case the LHS is not defined at $\pi/4$, so they are not the same (At least not everywhere, as it would be in this case).

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper fair point. Awesome name btw.

Comment: OK. I have asked her to check the problem with 2sin^3, she can only confirm tomorrow though. Would be appreciated if you could show the steps with 2sin^3

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thanks a ton

Comment: If one should be nitpicking, the left-hand side cannot be defined as that quotient at $\theta=n\pi/4$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, since then the denominator is zero. It turns out, however, that the numerator is also zero at those points (except the ones for which $\theta=\pi/4+n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$), so if one defines the quotient in the left-hand side by the natural limits at the interesting points, the identity hold.

Comment: Seriously wish for this community the site allows to check multiple answers as the correct one

Comment: Please don't simply post homework problems here for others to do. The goal of this site is to answer questions about mathematics, but not simply to do homework for others. If you have attempted the problem yourself, explain where you got stuck. And give the source of the problem, as well. You can edit the post to add this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the change to the problem discussed in the comments, then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(\theta) - 2\sin^3(\theta)}{2\cos^3(\theta) - \cos(\theta)} &= \tan(\theta) \\
\frac{\sin(\theta) - 2\sin^3(\theta)}{2\cos^3(\theta) - \cos(\theta)} &= \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)} \\
\frac{1 - 2\sin^2(\theta)}{2\cos^2(\theta) - 1} &= 1\\
1 - 2\sin^2(\theta) &= 2\cos^2(\theta) -1 \\
2 &= 2\sin^2(\theta) + 2\cos^2(\theta)
\end{align*}

which is a true statement. Since all steps are reversible the identity is true.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, the identity is only valid when the denominator of the fraction on the LHS is not zero, so for $\theta$ for which $2\cos^3(\theta) - \cos(\theta) \not= 0$. In other words $\cos(\theta) \not= 0$ and $|\cos(\theta) | \not= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, so $\theta \not= \frac{\pi}{2}k$ and $\theta \not= \frac{\pi}{4}k$ for all odd $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Otherwise the identity is true.

Comment: As @LeviathanTheEsper said its only valid if $\theta \neq \pi/4$

Comment: Or some other values, since the functions are periodic. The statement is true "almost everywhere", said in a little informal way.

Comment: Now finally we got an identity and aras provided the steps for the proof. No point keeping an incorrect identity in the question

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper Good point, added in an edit to the answer.

Comment: @leviathantheesper That discontinuity is removeable, is it not? So, ...

Comment: Yes, it can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Notice,

The trig identity will hold if we have $\sin^3\theta$ in place of $\sin^2\theta$ in the numerator of LHS as follows $$LHS=\frac{\sin\theta-2\sin^3\theta}{2\cos^3\theta-\cos \theta}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\theta(1-2\sin^2\theta)}{\cos\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1)}$$
$$=\tan \theta\left(\frac{1-2\sin^2\theta}{2(1-\sin^2\theta)-1}\right)$$
$$=\tan \theta\left(\frac{1-2\sin^2\theta}{1-2\sin^2\theta}\right)$$$$=\tan\theta=RHS$$

Answer (score 1):

Recognizing sin/cos of double angles in numerator and denominator,

$$ \tan \theta = \frac{\sin \theta * \cos 2\theta}{\cos \theta * \cos 2 \theta}  \frac{}{} $$

so the identity is true.